# How to extract certain value from nested list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I have lists like this

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [[1,4],[2,10],[3,11],[5,15],[20,30]]
```

I want to extract the numbers if the first number of the list2 is in the list1, therefore the output will be like:

```
list3 = [1,2,3,4,10,11]
```

Anyone can help me with how to do that?

Comment: The size of inner lists always 2 in`list2`?

Comment: Please post the code that's giving you the problem -- see [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Simply handing us a coding problem is not generally acceptable on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following using the transpositional [`zip(*...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) pattern, if the order derives from `list2`:

```
from itertools import chain

>>> list(chain(*zip(*(p for p in list2 if p[0] in list1))))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11]
```

If the order of the elements is based on the order in `list1`:

```
>>> d = dict(list2)
>>> list(chain(list1, map(d.get, list1)))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11]
```

Instead of using the cryptic [`chain(*iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) pattern, you can also use the more explicit [`chain.from_iterable(iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable).